# How To Testing (Unit and Instrumented) of Okhttp

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin

I'm doing self-learning of android (mostly), and I'm can't grasp a concept about Testing. I tried googling and youtube but still don't get it, so I really need a sample to test my code below

Could anyone show me how to create unit test request data to server from this code?

```
    fun fetchJSON() {

    val url =baseurl + prevnext  + idliga

    val request = Request.Builder().url(url).build()

    val client = OkHttpClient()

    client.newCall(request).enqueue(object: Callback {
        override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {

        }

        override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
            val body = response.body()?.string()
            val gson = GsonBuilder().create()

            val DataMatch= gson.fromJson(body, DataPertandingan::class.java)

            runOnUiThread {

                 rvPrevMatch.adapter= PrevAdapter(DataMatch)
            }
        }
    })

}
```

And about the instrumented test, how do I test adding something to SQLite.

here is my activity code of adding data to SQLite.

```
private fun addToFavorite() {
    try {
        database.use {
            insert(
                Favorite.DATA_FAVORITE,
               Favorite.ID_EVENT to id_event,
                Favorite.DATE to tanggaltandingdet.text,

                // home team
               Favorite.HOME_ID to idhome,
                Favorite.HOME_TEAM to timkandangdet.text,
                Favorite.HOME_SCORE to skorkandangdet.text,
                Favorite.HOME_GOAL_DETAILS to cetakgolkandang.text,
                Favorite.HOME_LINEUP_GOALKEEPER to kiperkandang.text,
                Favorite.HOME_LINEUP_DEFENSE to bekkandang.text,
                Favorite.HOME_LINEUP_MIDFIELD to midkandang.text,
                Favorite.HOME_LINEUP_FORWARD to strikerkandang.text,
                Favorite.HOME_LINEUP_SUBSTITUTES to cadangankandang.text,
            //    Favorite.HOME_TEAM_BADGE to urllogokandang.text,

                // away team
                Favorite.AWAY_ID to idaway,
                Favorite.AWAY_TEAM to timtandangdet.text,
                Favorite.AWAY_SCORE to skortandangdet.text,
                Favorite.AWAY_GOAL_DETAILS to cetakgoltandang.text,
                Favorite.AWAY_LINEUP_GOALKEEPER to kipertandang.text,
                Favorite.AWAY_LINEUP_DEFENSE to bektandang.text,
                Favorite.AWAY_LINEUP_MIDFIELD to midtandang.text,
                Favorite.AWAY_LINEUP_FORWARD to strikertandang.text,
                Favorite.AWAY_LINEUP_SUBSTITUTES to cadangantandang.text
            //    Favorite.AWAY_TEAM_BADGE to urllogotandang.text

            )
        }

        toast ("Data Telah Di Simpan"  )
    } catch (e: SQLiteConstraintException) {
        toast("Error: ${e.message}")
    }
}
```

Comment: use mockito. mock HTTP client and its response.

Comment: *Could anyone show me how to create unit test* - no, because we don't know what you want to test

Comment: Tim , from the code above i asked to do 2 testing.1. Unit Testing (request data to server), and 2nd is to test about adding data to sqllite (instrumented i guess).  I seek about mockito e.t.c  but i still don't understand

Comment: Any sample about what to test and how to test it will be very useful for my knowledge